# Why does the square matrix change when I loop through it?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

When I loop thru a matrix to get the diagonals:

```
a = [[11, 2, 4],
     [4, 5, 6],
     [10, 8, -12]]

i = 0
o = 0
for a[i] in a:
    d1 = a[i][o]
    o += 1
    print(d1)
```

the output is like expected `11, 5, -12`,
but when I print out the matrix again:

```
print(a)
```

the matrix changed

```
[[10, 8, -12], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
```

the first row is no more like it was `[11, 2, 4]`.

I can't figure out why is that happening.

Comment: `for a[i] in a:` is your problem (reassigning the elements of `a[0]` on each iteration), but since I don't know what you want to do, I can't suggest how you should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning each element of a to the first element of a. See the following code.

```
for a[0] in a:
    print(a)
```

This yields:

```
[[11, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
[[10, 8, -12], [4, 5, 6], [10, 8, -12]]
```

a[0] is first reassigned to [11,2,4], then to [4,5,6], then finally to [10,8,-12]. a[1] and a[2] are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of lists represents a square matrix, use a single loop inside a list comprehension to extract diagonals:

```
>>> [a[i][i] for i in range(len(a))]
[11, 5, -12]
```

---

I'm not sure where you came across this `for a[i] in a` syntax, but that does not do what you think it does. It ends up reassigning the 0th element to whatever the for loop is iterating over as a side effect, so don't do it.

Incidentally, fixing your code, it would be:

```
d = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    d.append(a[i][i])
```

Which is just an explicit re-writing of the list comprehension above.